# How to use OPENQUERY to properly execute a Stored Procedure that updates a linked server table?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I'm having a hard time trying to figure this out. I'm using `OPENQUERY` to execute Stored Procedures on a linked server. I managed to find a way to do it, by using the following:

```
SELECT *    
FROM   OPENQUERY(
[LINKEDSRV\SQLSRV],  
'SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC [Database_Name_Example].Data.usp_GetNames 5,''S''')   
GO
```

The reason I use `SET FMTONLY` OFF and `SET NOCOUNT ON` is because when I tried the code above without them, this message appeared:

> Msg 7357, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot process the object "EXEC
>   [Database_Name_Example].Data.usp_GetNames 5,'S'". The OLE DB provider
>   "SQLNCLI" for linked server "LINKEDSRV\SQLSRV" indicates that either
>   the object has no columns or the current user does not have
>   permissions on that object.

Reading a lot online helped me find the answer. This blog for example: http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#OPENQUERY

So far so good, until I stomped into a Stored Procedure that use `SELECT` and `UPDATE` some tables on the linked server. When I execute the `OPENQUERY` I get the results from the `SELECT` statement but I noticed that it does not update the table.

The Stored Procedure goes like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Data.usp_GetNames (@year tinyint=NULL, @online char(1)=NULL)
if @online = 'S'    
  BEGIN
    select nam_codig, nam_desc from Names
    where nam_status = 'P'
    order by nam_date

    UPDATE Names
    SET nam_status = 'S'
    where nam_status = 'P'
END
```

When I execute it directly in the linked server it updates the table, so the second time I execute it, there will be no more `nam_status = 'P'`

But if I execute it with `OPENQUERY` the results are the same, it doesn't `UPDATE` it just select the data.

What can I do to allow the permissions?

Thank you!!!

Comment: @JohnEisbrener That works perfectly!!! It didn't give me any problem. How did I miss that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [four-part naming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks) instead of using `OPENQUERY` to execute stored procedures via a linked server:

```
EXECUTE [LINKEDSRV\SQLSRV].[Database_Name_Example].Data.usp_GetNames 5,'S'
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenRowset is primarily designed for retrieving data, though you can use it to insert and execute stored procedures. I would recommend that you switch to CLR function for executing the remote stored procedure. Heres a simple code you can compile to a .net assembly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ETL
{
    public class SQLServer
    {

        [SqlFunction(Name = "ExecSQL", SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.Read, DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
        public static SqlString ExecSQL(string server, string Database, string cmdSQL)
        {
            string rValue = "0";
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(string.Format(@"Server={0};DataBase={1};Integrated Security=SSPI", server.ToString(), Database.ToString())))
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(cmdSQL.ToString(), conn)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            })
            {
                command.CommandTimeout = 800;
                conn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                rValue = "1";  
            }
            return rValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Good Luck :)